# how to draw a elegant vertical line between two divs placed up and down?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs placed up and down as mentioned in the image. I want to draw a vertical connecting line between these two divs. I used pipe (|) font to do this. But, it is not looking elegant. Can someone help me to draw an elegant vertical line between the divs?

[image]

Comment: https://gojs.net/latest/ something like that?

Comment: Please include your code. We need to see a [mcve] to ensure our solutions will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use border-left:4px dashed blue; property to create a dashed line for connecting the two divs.

```css
.box {
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  height:70px;
  background: grey;
}
.vl {
  border-left: 4px dashed blue;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left:50%
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="vl"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```